# How Do We Create One PDF Page Per Slide (Not Per Fragment)?

Tags: reveal.js

It used to be that reveal.js would generate one PDF page per slide. Now, as of [this issue](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1584), it generates one PDF page per fragment. I would like to generate a PDF in the old one-page-per-slide format, though.

[This comment on that issue](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1584#issuecomment-396200732) suggests that there is a configuration option for this, but it's not obvious what it is from the project documentation.

Which configuration option controls this? Or, is there another way to get reveal.js PDF export to do one page per slide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js)' [README.md](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/README.md), under [PDF Export](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/README.md#pdf-export) > [Separate pages for fragments](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/README.md#separate-pages-for-fragments):

> [Fragments](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/README.md#fragments) are printed on separate slides by default. Meaning if you have a slide with three fragment steps, it will generate three separate slides where the fragments appear incrementally.
>
> If you prefer printing all fragments in their visible states on the same slide you can set the `pdfSeparateFragments` config option to false.

So, it seems you can export multiple fragments per page via:

```js
Reveal.configure({ pdfSeparateFragments: false });
```

Comment: I am not certain how I missed that!